# Reactive Mongo Flux methods opening two many connections pools

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, flux, spring-flex

I have a ReactiveMongoRepository with a method that returns Flux
whenever the method is called it opens a new connection

```
Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:118, serverValue:44}]
```

till it exeeds 100 than it throws

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=54.37.81.35:58789, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /54.37.81.35:58789}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
   at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:167) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar:na]
```

becouse no pool is available anymore. Any idea how to solve or any suggestion ?

Thanks,

Comment: can you add this code in your code block. `@Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
        return MongoClientOptions.builder().threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(2).maxConnectionIdleTime(1).connectionsPerHost(1).minConnectionsPerHost(1).socketTimeout(2000).build();
    }`

Comment: did you solve this? I also have this problem

Comment: I face the same issue. In an integration test, it opens from 8 up to 40 connections. Just for inserting 200 elements and making some grouping. This is not scalable.